# ¿Cómo leer o interpretar una consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Cómo se puede leer o interpretar el resultado de esta consulta?

```
SELECT a.PurchaseOrderID
        ,b.PurchaseOrderID
        ,a.VendorID
        ,a.ShipMethodID
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader AS a
JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader AS b
    ON  a.VendorID = b.VendorID
    AND a.ShipMethodID = b.ShipMethodID
WHERE a.PurchaseOrderID < b.PurchaseOrderID
```

Comment: Está agrupando los registros de la tabla PurchaseOrderHeader con si misma donde tengan el mismo VendorID y ShipMethodID pero de fechas anteriores entre una y otra instancia, no me queda clara la intención de la consulta, puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar mas información por favor

Comment: @AlejandroMedina me temo que estás equivocado, no se está agrupando nada, solo se está haciendo un `self-join`. Tampoco se mencionan fechas, no sé por qué haces referencia a eso ;)

Comment: @Flxtr tienes razón, use la palabra "agrupando" para refererirme al JOIN, se puede malinterpretar por existir la sentencia GROUP, ¿existe alguna forma de traducir JOIN ?... más o menos significa Unir, pero también existe la sentencia UNION de SQL https://translate.google.com/#auto/es/join

Comment: Sigo reflexionando al respecto, básicamente el JOIN es la union de dos conjuntos... https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uni%C3%B3n_de_conjuntos

Comment: @AlejandroMedina Quiero saber como interpretar el resultado, en palabras comunes como lo leería.

Comment: @Kevin es una tarea escolar?

Comment: Me parece que el JOIN si podría decirse que es la combinación de campos con campos y la UNION es unir registros de diferentes tablas con misma estructura.

Comment: Para que puedas interperat una consulta, básate de primer instancia en las condiciones. Yo la interpretaría algo asi como: Obtener todos los registros del mismo proveedor `VendorID`, mismo método de pago `ShipMethodID` pero que el número de orden de compra no sea el más reciente, o sea el menor, o no sea el más alto :)